# Eventual pointwise monotonicity implies eventually increasing/decreasing on open interval

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real-valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Suppose that for each $x \in [0,1]$, the sequence $(f_{n}(x))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is eventually monotone (that is, there is an $N_{x} \geq 1$ such that the sequence $(f_{n}(x))_{n=N_{x}}^{\infty}$ is monotone). Show that there exists an open interval $I \subseteq [0,1]$ and $N \geq 1$ such that the sequences $(f_{n}(x))_{n=N}^{\infty}$, $x \in I$ are all either increasing or decreasing.

My idea is to use the fact that continuous functions on $[0,1]$ are uniformly continuous and to do a proof by contradiction: if every open interval contains points which are both eventually increasing or decreasing, then we should be able to find some points which move away from each other eventually and violate uniform continuity.

Comment: Assume WLOG that $f_n(0)$ is eventually increasing. Let $x_0$ be the supremum of the set of all $x$ for which $f_n(y)$ is eventually increasing for all $y\le x$. Is it possible for $f_n(x_0)$ to be eventually increasing? Is it possible for it to be evenually decreasing?

Comment: Still  not completely sure to proceed, but I think the limiting behavior of the sequences is like so: a collection of disjoint open intervals of *strict* monotone behavior broken up by points at which the functions are eventually stationary.

Comment: So it seems like you should try to show that $x_0$ is a point at which $f_n(x_0)$ is eventually increasing and decreasing, hence stationary.

Comment: It was only an idea - I hadn't pursued it, which is why I made it a comment - but if $x_0 > 0$, then $(0, x_0)$ is the interval you are after. If $x_0 = 0$, and there is no $N$ after which $f_n(0)$ is constant, then no $x$ sufficiently close to $0$ can be decreasing, as the rising of $f_n(0)$ prevents it. Hence $f_(0)$ must be eventually constant. But that means it is also eventually decreasing and you can do the argument in the other direction to show that nearby $f_n(x)$ cannot be increasing. Hence there is a stretch that is constant. That is my idea, but it may not pan out.